# In-app purchases selling music

Tags: ios, xcode

I've read their IAP documentation but couldn't find a clear answer.
Can I sell my own music (hosted on my server) using IAP?

Will Apple approve my app?

Comment: For the sake of making your users lives easier, you should sell your music in iTunes and link to it in your app. This way when they download your music it will be directly added to their iPod library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use IAP and have the proper rights to sell the music there will be no problem at all.

Maybe this will help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1